# StackOverflowError generating a JasperReport

Tags: java, stack-overflow

Good morning!

I am generating a pdf report with jasperreport.

This pdf contains several sheets, seven (7) in total. But when the user click it to get the report the server throws this error:

[Servlet Error]-[action]: java.lang.StackOverflowError at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.serializedMember(DefaultMapper.java:122)

Somebody can help me? Thank you!

The code is in bottom

The trace is:

```
  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.serializedMember(DefaultMapper.java:122)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.serializedMember(MapperWrapper.java:30)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.serializedMember(MapperWrapper.java:30)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.serializedMember(MapperWrapper.java:30)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.FieldAliasingMapper.serializedMember(FieldAliasingMapper.java:45)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.serializedMember(MapperWrapper.java:30)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.serializedMember(MapperWrapper.java:30)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.serializedMember(MapperWrapper.java:30)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.serializedMember(MapperWrapper.java:30)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.serializedMember(MapperWrapper.java:30)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.serializedMember(MapperWrapper.java:30)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.serializedMember(MapperWrapper.java:30)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.OuterClassMapper.serializedMember(OuterClassMapper.java:41)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.serializedMember(MapperWrapper.java:30)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.serializedMember(MapperWrapper.java:30)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.serializedMember(MapperWrapper.java:30)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.serializedMember(MapperWrapper.java:30)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:91)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:81)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:109)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:66)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:41)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:59)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:50)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.AnnotationReflectionConverter.marshallField(AnnotationReflectionConverter.java:37)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:105)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:81)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:109)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:66)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:41)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:59)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:50)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.AnnotationReflectionConverter.marshallField(AnnotationReflectionConverter.java:37)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:105)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:81)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:109)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:66)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:41)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:59)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:50)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.AnnotationReflectionConverter.marshallField(AnnotationReflectionConverter.java:37)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:105)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:81)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:109)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:66)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:41)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:59)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:50)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.AnnotationReflectionConverter.marshallField(AnnotationReflectionConverter.java:37)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:105)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:81)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:109)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:66)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:41)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:59)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:50)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.AnnotationReflectionConverter.marshallField(AnnotationReflectionConverter.java:37)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:105)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:81)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:109)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:66)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:41)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:59)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:50)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.AnnotationReflectionConverter.marshallField(AnnotationReflectionConverter.java:37)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:105)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:81)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:109)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:66)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:41)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:59)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:50)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.AnnotationReflectionConverter.marshallField(AnnotationReflectionConverter.java:37)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:105)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:81)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:109)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:66)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:41)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:59)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:50)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.AnnotationReflectionConverter.marshallField(AnnotationReflectionConverter.java:37)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:105)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:81)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:109)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:66)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:41)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:59)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:50)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.AnnotationReflectionConverter.marshallField(AnnotationReflectionConverter.java:37)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:105)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:81)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:109)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:66)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:41)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:59)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:50)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.AnnotationReflectionConverter.marshallField(AnnotationReflectionConverter.java:37)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:105)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:81)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:109)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:66)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:41)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:59)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:50)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.AnnotationReflectionConverter.marshallField(AnnotationReflectionConverter.java:37)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:105)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:81)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:109)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:66)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:41)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:59)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:50)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.AnnotationReflectionConverter.marshallField(AnnotationReflectionConverter.java:37)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:105)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:81)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:109)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:66)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:41)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:59)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:50)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.AnnotationReflectionConverter.marshallField(AnnotationReflectionConverter.java:37)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:105)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:81)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:109)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:66)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:41)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:59)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:50)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.AnnotationReflectionConverter.marshallField(AnnotationReflectionConverter.java:37)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:105)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:81)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:109)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:66)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:41)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:59)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:50)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.AnnotationReflectionConverter.marshallField(AnnotationReflectionConverter.java:37)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:105)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:81)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:109)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:66)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:41)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:59)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:50)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.AnnotationReflectionConverter.marshallField(AnnotationReflectionConverter.java:37)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:105)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:81)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:109)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:66)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:41)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:59)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:50)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.AnnotationReflectionConverter.marshallField(AnnotationReflectionConverter.java:37)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:105)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:81)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:109)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:66)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:41)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:59)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:50)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.AnnotationReflectionConverter.marshallField(AnnotationReflectionConverter.java:37)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:105)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:81)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:109)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:66)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:41)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:59)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:50)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.AnnotationReflectionConverter.marshallField(AnnotationReflectionConverter.java:37)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:105)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:81)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:109)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:66)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:41)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:59)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:50)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.AnnotationReflectionConverter.marshallField(AnnotationReflectionConverter.java:37)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:105)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:81)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:109)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:66)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:41)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:59)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:50)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.AnnotationReflectionConverter.marshallField(AnnotationReflectionConverter.java:37)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:105)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:81)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:109)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:66)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:41)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:59)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:50)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.AnnotationReflectionConverter.marshallField(AnnotationReflectionConverter.java:37)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:105)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:81)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:109)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:66)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:41)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:59)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:50)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.AnnotationReflectionConverter.marshallField(AnnotationReflectionConverter.java:37)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:105)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:81)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:109)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:66)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:41)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:59)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:50)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.AnnotationReflectionConverter.marshallField(AnnotationReflectionConverter.java:37)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:105)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:81)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:109)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:66)

  at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:41)
```

The code is:

public void generatePDFSReport(List template, Reportable reportable, Map parameters, OutputStream output){

```
        Object[] reportableObj= {reportable};

        if(parameters==null){
            parameters = new HashMap();
            parameters.put("RutaImagen", basePath + templatesFolder + templatesImageFolder);
        }else {
            parameters.put("RutaImagen", basePath + templatesFolder + templatesImageFolder);
        }

        try {
            List printList =  new ArrayList();

            for (Iterator iter = template.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
                String fileName = (String) iter.next();
            try {
                String file = JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(basePath + templatesFolder +fileName, parameters, new JRBeanArrayDataSource(reportableObj));
                printList.add(JRLoader.loadObject(file));
            } catch (JRException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            }

            JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();

            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, printList);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, output);

            exporter.exportReport();    


        } catch(JRException  e){
            throw new InfinixRuntimeException("No se creo el reporte",e);
        }

     }
```

public ConsultarPreSolicitudConfirmarDTO imprimirSolicitudCredito(ConsultarPreSolicitudConfirmarDTO dto, DetallePreSolicitudConfirmadaDTO preSolicitud) {
        final String error ="No se pudo imprimir la Solicitud de Crédito";

```
    try {

        List plantillas = new ArrayList();
        plantillas.add("SolicitudDeCredito.jasper");
        plantillas.add("SolicitudDeCredito_2.jasper");
        plantillas.add("SolicitudDeCredito_3.jasper");
        plantillas.add("SolicitudDeCredito_4.jasper");
        plantillas.add("SolicitudDeCredito_5.jasper");
        plantillas.add("SolicitudDeCredito_6.jasper");
        plantillas.add("SolicitudDeCredito_7.jasper");      

        reporteService.generatePDFSReport(plantillas, preSolicitud, null, dto.getPdf());

        logger.logError("******* Se genera la Solicitud de Crédito *********");

    } catch (BusinessRuntimeException e) {
        dto.addErrors(e.getErrors());
        logger.logDebug(error);
    } catch(InfinixRuntimeException e) {
        dto.addError(new InfinixError("81452"));
        logger.logError("No se pudo imprimir el reporte", e);
    }
```

Comment: StackoverflowError on Stackoverflow! Nice!

Answer (score 0):

I guess, because of `for (Iterator iter = template.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {` you are ending in infinte-loop which throws `StackOverflowError`.

I think your code should be something like this.

```
Iterator iter = template.iterator(); 
while (iter.hasNext();) {
                String fileName = (String) iter.next();
            try {
                String file = JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(basePath + templatesFolder +fileName, parameters, new JRBeanArrayDataSource(reportableObj));
                printList.add(JRLoader.loadObject(file));
            } catch (JRException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks! I will do the change and I test it! But, Is not the same? The clause "for" have iter.hasNext() too

Comment: @EdgarTrejo: I need to write a test and see. But I suspect they are not same.